# Maximum call stack size exceeded in mongo update

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to update mongo db field using node js but it shows the error:

> Maximum call stack size exceeded

and this is my code:

```
var async = require('async');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = function (app) {
Tweets.find().exec(function(err, oldTweets){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    else{
        //console.log(oldTweets);
        console.log('=== MIGRATION OF TWEETS STARTS ===');
        async.eachSeries(oldTweets, function(tweet, iterateNext){


            Tweets.update( { _id:tweet._id }, { $rename: { 'celebrityId': 'entityId' } } ).exec(function(err, cel){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                }
                else{
                    console.log(cel);
                    iterateNext(null);
                }
            });
        }, function(err){
            console.log('=== MIGRATION ENDED ===');
        }); 
    }
});
```

};

Answer (score 0):

## This is taken *directly* from the documentation for async https://github.com/caolan/async#synchronous-iteration-functions

---

> #### Synchronous iteration functions
>
> If you get an error like `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.` or other stack overflow issues when using async, you are likely using a synchronous iterator.  By *synchronous* we mean a function that calls its callback on the same tick in the javascript event loop, without doing any I/O or using any timers.  Calling many callbacks iteratively will quickly overflow the stack. If you run into this issue, just defer your callback with `async.setImmediate` to start a new call stack on the next tick of the event loop.